# C pipe() and fork()

Tags: c

I have a problem with a simple program im making with fork and pipes for learning purpose. I want a child that send the ppid to the parent to output the value of ppid and do this twice. However,the result is two ppid output are the same.Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int   fd[2];  /* for the pipe */
  int   n,pid,ppid,val;
  int   p[5],q[5];

  if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
     printf("Pipe creation error\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  for(val=0;val<2;val++){
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        ppid = getpid();
        printf("child %d pid:%d \n",val+1,ppid);
        write(fd[1], &ppid, sizeof(ppid));
        sleep(1);
        close(fd[1]);

    } else { /* parent */
   //printf("Parent: pid: ");
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("%d \n",val+1);
        sleep(1);
        n = read(fd[0], &ppid ,sizeof(ppid));
        printf("%d \n",ppid);

        // fflush(stdout);
        close(fd[0]);
        wait(NULL);
        // printf("<parent> I have completed!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh? You're sending a value from the child to the parent over the pipe and printing it; of course it's exactly the same as in the child.

Comment: Program looks fine to me. Possible confusion: do you want to send the pid, or the ppid ?

Comment: Question is also dsiturbingly similar to another one out there with similar name.

Answer (score 0):

There may be potential problem in the program design. Since the parent waits for the child 
in the first iteration, the child executes the for loop for val=1 and spawns another process
through fork. Eventually there are three process of which two of them will have the same pid 
as one of them is executing the for twice.